# WP site, ASP.net Web API ApiController

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wordpress, authentication, asp.net-apicontroller

We are building our public facing website on Wordpress and on a Linux server. The user will be logging into the WordPress site with OAuth2. Our data and API is going to be built on an ASP.net MVC4 server. I have a couple of problems that I need to resolve and am trying to figure out the most secure way to Authenticate on the IIS server.
1. I need to authenticate with Wordpress.
2. I need to associate customer numbers to the login from 1 above.
3. Somehow I need to then be able to use that associated customer number and some for of Authentication to allow the IIS server to service the requested API.

Some thoughts were to store some kind of UUID for each customer number and store it on the WP and IIS server and then when the request comes in to IIS confirm that the passed UUID matches what was issued to the WP server in step 2 above. My concern is though that this UUID could be compromised/forged at a later time and that UUID could be used to make calls to the API on the IIS server.

What is the best way to implement security on the IIS server that allows the customer to login only on the Wordpress server?

Comment: You want to authenticate the same users both on the IIS and the server with the API? Why don't you authenticate them only in Wordpress, and use some single credential for Wordpress to consume whatever it is that your API has?

Comment: I only want to authenticate them on WP but the API on IIS7 will be called possibly from Angular or Jquery on the page. So there is a slight disjunct between the two.

Comment: If I was going to use only server side calls to the API and could lock down the IIS to only service the WP server I would, and may yet have to do it that way. WP development is going to be done by someone else and I am doing the API programming.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently using a Custom Http Authentication Module in IIS, so when I need to consume the web api from WP, I follow this approach: I build petition with my custom authentication rules (example: you can use a custom http header, o something else to pass credentials), in web api side, I check credentials (using http authentication module, of course), if everything is fine, http authentication module allow requests, if not, It deny request.